# `systemctl --user disable` for distro-shipped services?

Tags: ubuntu, services, systemd

I ran `systemctl --user disable tracker-miner-fs.service` expecting to see some changes in the filesystem and in the status output, but

```
XUb ~$ systemctl --user disable tracker-miner-fs.service 
XUb ~$ systemctl --user status tracker-miner-fs.service 
● tracker-miner-fs.service - Tracker file system data miner
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/tracker-miner-fs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
...
```

The service seems to be enabled via `/etc/systemd/user/`:

```
$ find `systemd-analyze --user unit-paths` 2>/dev/null  | grep tracker
/etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants/tracker-miner-fs.service
/etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants/tracker-extract.service
...
```

So how can I disable vendor-shipped user services, preferably as a user (on an individual basis) or as root (for all users)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the globally-enabled user service for all users by running (as root):

```sh
systemctl --global disable tracker-miner-fs.service
```

I'm not aware of a way to disable a globally-enabled user service for an individual user, although you could prevent the service from being run by [masking](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-masking-units/) it:

```sh
systemctl --user mask tracker-miner-fs.service
```

If you still wanted to be able to start the service manually, you could create a copy with a different name.  (I realize that's probably not ideal.  I'm not aware of a better solution.)

Comment: That's what I ended up doing... So basically `systemctl --user disable` is meaningless, as there is no place for systemd to save the per-user dis/en-abled status?

Comment: @AldIn `systemctl --user disable` can remove symlinks created by `systemctl --user enable` (i.e. disable non-globals), but I agree it is less useful than it could be, and that per-user disabling of globals would be useful.  The current behavior is also confusing, as noted in [systemd/systemd#18271](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/18271) (which is how I came across your question).

Comment: A similar question: how to stop a user service for all users? When uninstalling a package with a user service I can globally disable it and stop for a current user but can't figure out how to stop for all users who are online in the the system

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654846 answers your question?  If not, I'd encourage you to ask the question as a question, rather than a comment to an answer, so you can get better answers and others can benefit.